# Ecommerce HTML Cleaner?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to scrape eBay via Selenium but it's difficult to extract the required data. I know there are tools that allow you to clean HTML data in order to extract the "article" and remove the clutter.

Are there any tools in Java that allow you to extract relevant data from Ecommerce sites? For example, I need to extract product title, description and other product details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Selenium but have you tried the [eBay SDK for Java](https://go.developer.ebay.com/javasdk)? I'm guessing you can get all you want and it should be significantly faster than browsing and scraping pages.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it. I did want to scrape it via Selenium (or some other tool) in order to avoid using the API (preferably)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/ebay-search-api) to extract data from eBay, Walmart, and HomeDepot. Free trial accounts are available.

[Full example](https://repl.it/@serpapi/scrape-ebay-java)

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import serpapi.SerpApiSearchException;
import serpapi.EbaySearch;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import static java.util.Map.entry;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>(Map.ofEntries(
      entry("_nkw", "Coffee cup"), 
      entry("api_key", System.getenv("API_KEY")))
    );

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {
      EbaySearch search = new EbaySearch(parameters);

      SerpApiResponseDTO response = gson.fromJson(search.getJson(), SerpApiResponseDTO.class);

      for (OrganicResultDTO organicResult : response.organicResults) {
        String message = String.format("title: %s\nshipping: %s\nprice: %s\n----", organicResult.title,
            organicResult.shipping, organicResult.price.raw);

        System.out.println(message);
      }
    } catch (SerpApiSearchException ex) {
      System.out.println("oops something went wrong when search " + parameters.get("_nkw") + " on eBay");
      ex.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}

class SerpApiResponseDTO {
  @SerializedName("organic_results")
  OrganicResultDTO[] organicResults;
}

class OrganicResultDTO {
  String title;
  String shipping;
  PriceDTO price;
}

class PriceDTO {
  double extracted;
  String raw;
}
```

**Output**

```
title: Custom Photo Mug Coffee Cup Picture Photo Text Phrase Logo Personalized Gift
shipping: Free shipping
price: $14.99
----
title: Automatic Self Stirring Coffee Mixing Cup Mug 400ml Electric Stainless Steel NEW
shipping: Free shipping
price: $7.99
----
title: Grinch Cup Of Fuckoffee One Splash No One Cares Gift Black Coffee Mug
shipping: Free shipping
price: $19.99

...
```

**Disclaimer**: I work at SerpApi.